# Using javascript without jQuery to call current element

Tags: javascript

First i'm sory for my bad english :)
I have some code here :

```
<style>
    .active circle {fill:red;}
    .deactive circle {fill:black;}
</style>
<form>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="btn1"/>
    <svg class="deactive">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
    </svg>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="btn2"/>
    <svg class="a">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
    </svg>
</form>
```

I want to change circle class went click button with javascript, not use jQuery.
Ex : I click first button the first circle will change class to "active" and second circle class is "deactive".
If i click second button the first circle class will replace to "deactive" and second circle class replace to "active"

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Please use different identifiers for each button , set the identifier for  tag and use following code it will work well:

```
document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function(e)
{
   document.getElementById("svg1").setAttribute("class","active"); 
   document.getElementById("svg2").setAttribute("class","deactive");
}

document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = function(e)
{
  document.getElementById("svg1").setAttribute("class","deactive"); 
  document.getElementById("svg2").setAttribute("class","active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although possible it's not a recommended way to use an id more than once ([HTML id Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)), as it must to refer to an unique element in your body.

Apart this, using pure vanilla javascript instead of jQuery involves more code, see crossbrowser, DOM traversing, etc..

Anyway, you could take a look at this starting point if it could helps:

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="btn1"/>
<svg class="deactive">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
</svg>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="btn2"/>
<svg class="a">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
</svg>

<script>
    function changeClass(e)
    {
        var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var btnsLength = btns.length;

        for( var i = 0; i < btnsLength; i++)
        {
            btns[i].nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "deactive");
        }

        e.target.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "active");
    }

    document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', changeClass, false);
    document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', changeClass, false);  
</script>
```

Basically I just defined an handler for every button.

`document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', changeClass, false);`

This calls the function `changeClass`.

Inside this function I loop on every button and set the class `deactive` of its `nextElementSibling`.

At the end I set the class active **of the clicked element, passed as reference** `e` in the function `changeClass`

---------- Alternative starting point ------------

Another way to explore could be this:

```
function setElActive(el, event)
{
    document.getElementById(el).addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var btnsLength = btns.length;

        for( var i = 0; i < btnsLength; i++)
        {
            btns[i].nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "deactive");
        }

        e.target.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "active");
    }, false);

}

setElActive('btn1', 'click');
setElActive('btn2', 'click');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some background on how to understand the situation. First of all, you want to use Javascript's HTML DOM Api. It has numerous objects that you can use but in your particular case, you'd want to start with `document` object. It has [a lot of useful methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) to use and one particularly useful your situation is the [document.getElementById('btn');](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) It returns you a HTML DOM `element`.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('btn');
```

> **Note:** This call will find the **first** occurrence of an element with
>   id="btn" in your document and assign it's value to variable myElement.
>   Because the document.getElementById(id) will get the first occurrence,
>   you want to change the id on your second element having id="btn".
>   Otherwise you can never access it with javascript. If you use #btn for
>   styling, you should change the elements to use class="btn" and use
>   .btn{} in your css for styling and give each of the elements a unique
>   id within the page.

Now, since you have a value in the `var myElement`, which is of type `element`, you can use ([the DOM Element methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)) to manipulate the element.

However, in your case, you don't want to manipulate the element itself. Not at least yet. You want to do it after an `Event`. This is you you want to attach an `Event Listener` to the element. There are numerous things (again) that you can do with [event object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp). Some of them you can use with an `element` such as [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).

So, adding to your previous code, you would then have:

```
// Find the element and assign it to myElement
var myElement = document.getElementById('btn');

// Attach an event to the element by using the variable myElement
myElement.onclick = function(evt){
    var clickedElement = evt.target;
};
```

The function that handles the click, will have one input parameter, `evt`. You can choose whatever name you want for it but it will always be of type [Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp). Now, within your function, you can use the evt variable to find the clicked element again from the event properties. In this case, you'd use [target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp), which holds the `Element` that was clicked.

```
// Find the element and assign it to myElement
var myElement = document.getElementById('btn');

// Attach an event to the element by using the variable myElement
myElement.onclick = function(evt){
    var clickedElement = evt.target;
};
```

Since the clickedElement now holds a value of type `Element`, you can use [element's properties and methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) to manipulate and traverse the dom.

```
// Find the element and assign it to myElement
var myElement = document.getElementById('btn1');

// Attach an event to the element by using the variable myElement
myElement.onclick = function (evt) {

    // Find the clicked element
    var clickedElement = evt.target;
    // Set the clicked next svg element class to 'active'
    // Note: you need to traverse all the way to second sibiling because between
    // html elements, there are text nodes
    // (even though there is no text, the node exists)
    clickedElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.setAttribute('class', 'active');
};
```

Note: This example was given the html structure you had. In real life, you'd probably do this a lot different. For example you could give the svg elements also IDs to work with and come up with something like:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="btn1" />
    <svg id="svg1" class="deactive">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" />
    </svg>
    <input type="button" id="btn2" value="btn2" />
    <svg id="svg2" class="active">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" />
    </svg>
</form>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
// Find the element and assign it to myElement
var myElement = document.getElementById('btn1');

// Attach an event to the element by using the variable myElement
myElement.onclick = function (e) {
    // Find the svg elements and change their classes
    document.getElementById('svg1').setAttribute('class', 'active');
    document.getElementById('svg2').setAttribute('class', 'deactive');
};
```

Or you could use `addEventListener` like suggested in another post in this thread. I just wanted to give you some background so you will not only solve this particular problem but will be able to solve loads of them in the future.

Warning: Not all browsers **cough cough** implement the the dom the same way. F.ex. some versions of IE don't implement event.target but they use `event.srcElement` instead. This is why many people fall back to using libraries such as `jQuery`, that take these kinds of things into account and provide a common interface to code with all the browsers and their versions. However, you could easily come up with functions that bridge the gap between browsers.

```
function getEventTarget(evt){
    if (evt.target) return evt.target;
    if (evt.scrElement) return evt.srcElement;
    // and so forth
}
```

And call it in your code

```
myElement.onclick = function(evt){
    var clickedElement = getEventTarget(evt);
};
```

Happy coding! :)